# Ограничение FPS синхронно с скоростью монитора

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, vulkan

Как ограничить скорость выполнения программы привязав ее к "скорости монитора"? То есть если монитор 60 герц - основной цикл должен выполнятся 60 раз в секунду, если монитор 144 герц - 144 раза в секунду.

Много гуглил примеры, использовал `Sleep(), std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(), std::this_thread::sleep_for()` - полноценного нужного эффекта нет, возникают лишние задержки (не из-за тяжести программы, без задержек основной цикл работает 300 раз в секунду).

Мне нужна достичь именно такого эффекта, который дает включенный **V-Sync** в **Nvidia Control Panel**.

Когда я использовал `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` для получения нужной задержки, моя программа сжирала 7-9% процессора, а когда ограничивал скорость с помощью **V-Sync** из **Nvidia Control Panel** - программа сжирает всего 1-2% процессора.

Существует ли в С++ какая-нибудь функция, которая говорит программе заснуть пока монитор на начал заново обновлять кадр? Или какие еще есть способы добиться нужного эффекта?

Comment: Забавно - последний раз, когда сталкивался с синхронизацией с монитором - это были CGA, которые при несинхронном выводе "снежили", и вывод в видеопамять нужно было делать во время [обратного хода луча](http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v03/ch6_5.htm). Так что меня очень смущает синхронизация, не привязанная намертво к соответствующей аппаратуре, просто задержками - обязательно постепенно "уплывет"...

Comment: Скорее всего V-Sync и NCP используют ресурсы видеокарты. Из-за этого меньше нагрузка на проц.

Comment: Вместо ожидание обратного хода луча используется двойная буферизация контекста DC. Если используется 3-D ускоритель (OpenGL или DirectX) то с даной проблемой вы не столкнётесь.

Comment: Почитайте fps http://habrahabr.ru/company/wargaming/blog/265487/

Comment: Нашел решение, может кому пригодится - сделал средствами API (в данном случае Вулкан). Нужно было использовать формат представления VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR, а у меня был VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR. Проблема решилась полностью.